# passing JSON string from Spring controller to JasperReports - think I'm close

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

UPDATE - I've been able to get the report (without data) to show while passing the dataSource by removing my defaultdataadapter property in the report.  So now I THINK the JSON is getting to the report but I might not be using it right.  Should my  need to change when I'm passing the same JSON as a string instead of as a json file?  Please let me know if you have any suggestions in what I'm doing wrong passing the JSON data to my report - or getting it properly within my report.  Any help will be very much appreciated!!

==

I've been trying to get a simple *JasperReports* working by passing a JSON string to it in the controller. Since I'm using Java-style configuration for my Spring MVC app, I added this view resolver:

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleViewResolver getResourceBundleViewResolver(){
  ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();       
  resolver.setBasename("jasper-views");
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}
```

Then I created a jasper-views.properties file with the following:

```
myReport.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView
myReport.url=classpath:reports/test_report.jrxml
myReport.reportDataKey=dataSource
```

Now when I return "myReport" from my controller, it processes the report.  Here's what I'm doing in the controller:

```
@Controller
public class ReportingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getReport(ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception     
    {
        //using mongo's BasicDBObject for easy JSON creation
        BasicDBObject reportingData = new BasicDBObject();
        reportingData.put("name","value");
        BasicDBObject jsonObject = new BasicDBObject("reportingData", JSON.serialize(reportingData));
        JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(JSON.serialize(jsonObject).getBytes("UTF-8")), "reportingData");
        modelMap.put("dataSource", dataSource);
        modelMap.addAttribute("format", "html"); 
        return "myReport";
    }   
}
```

If I don't pass "reportingData" as the selectExpression (the 2nd param in the constructor to JsonDataSource), it renders the report properly - without the dynamic elements.  If I pass "reportingData", the report is blank.  From what I've read, it will be blank if the data source isn't passed properly.  But it appears that the JsonDataSource object is being populated with the data properly (from inspecting it in debug).  Please let me know if you have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE -  Here's the content of my report in case that helps.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="basic_reporting_main" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c86cc935-c657-48a6-8972-c27e4c0ebbf8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="IQReportingJSON"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[reportingData]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="200" height="30" forecolor="#0B9E9E" uuid="08154c9f-5698-407e-8646-1bdebd3221c1"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="15" width="100" height="20" uuid="96a8068d-0595-4736-890b-c796dbc8f070"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You can send Json string as a parameter to the report.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: `modelMap.put("jsonString", jsonString);`. Declare a parameter in jasper report with same name.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  With this approach, do I not even need to pass a JsonDataSource object to it?  And should the property be something like this?  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="jsonString"/>

Comment: I saw an example here http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824601/how-deploy-report-jasperserver-json-file-datasource - but it is accepting the name of the json file.  what should the property look like to accept the json string as the data source?  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source" value="http://localhost:port/jsonfilepath"/>

Comment: property should be of `java.lang.String` type and than later on extract values from it. Perhaps using a scriplet.

Comment: OK, I don't know how to do that.  Can you point me to an example of a report that accepts a JSON string from Java?